How can I make an iframe's contents match the behavior of css's object-fit:contain?
I am trying to embed an iframe containing a data visualization. I want the full contents of the graph to be visible on all device sizes (most of the utility comes from seeing the whole visualization). This would match the css property object-fit: contain. For example the intended behavior can be seen here under the Try it heading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
What I am getting now is more like object-fit:fill with a scrollbar. I have tried adjusting the height and width of the iframe to be responsive, but that isnt affecting how the content inside is set within the iframe. How can I make the content scale to be fully fit within the iframe or a parent element so that the full visualization is visible independent of the screen size?

If the iframe content itself is not responsive, so that it would adapt to the iframe's dimensions - then you will probably have to make the iframe larger in terms of width & height, and then scale the whole iframe down to the desired "target" dimensions.

This similar question also asks about scaling the contents of an iframe, but only in relation to width, not a combination of both width and height. Do you absolutely need to use an iframe? Could it just be a <div> instead?

Please edit your post to include the HTML/CSS/JS code both inside your iframe and outside.
